Passing self into a function of a struct instance of a field of a struct in Rust
So in rust, I have the following case:
I have two structs. Let's call them struct A and struct B. In struct A I have a vector of instances of struct B. In a method of struct A, I loop over every instance of struct B in struct A and call a method on it.
The method of struct B, that I call, needs a mutable reference to struct A and also a mutable reference to self. Therefore, I would have to iterate through the vector in A mutably (so there is the first mutable borrow) and then pass a mutable reference of A into the method of B (here is the second mutable borrow). Rust does not allow two mutable borrows at once, so does anybody have an idea how to either fix this, or restructure my code so that this works?
For reference, here is my current code:
for struct_b in self.struct_b_vec {
    struct_b.my_method(self);
}


if my_method needs access to both A and B then it should take &mut A and an index into the Vec<B>, that should give it all access needed.

The idea is to iterate on a vector of B which is not accessible from the reference to A passed as a parameter.
For this, we can temporarily take the content of the .struct_b_vec out of the structure member and put it back when the iterations are finished.
This can be done with std::mem::take() before the loop and a simple assignment after the loop.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    struct_b_vec: Vec<B>,
    count: usize,
}
impl A {
    fn use_all_b(&mut self) {
        /*
        for struct_b in self.struct_b_vec.iter_mut() {
            // ERROR: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
            struct_b.my_method(self);
        }
        */
        let mut struct_b_vec = std::mem::take(&mut self.struct_b_vec);
        for struct_b in struct_b_vec.iter_mut() {
            struct_b.my_method(self);
        }
        self.struct_b_vec = struct_b_vec;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B {
    i: usize,
}
impl B {
    fn my_method(
        &mut self,
        struct_a: &mut A,
    ) {
        self.i += 1; // mutate self
        struct_a.count += self.i; // mutate struct_a
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut struct_a = A {
        struct_b_vec: Vec::from_iter((0..4).map(|i| B { i })),
        count: 0,
    };
    struct_a.use_all_b();
    println!("{:?}", struct_a);
}
/*
A { struct_b_vec: [B { i: 1 }, B { i: 2 }, B { i: 3 }, B { i: 4 }], count: 10 }
*/

When doing something equivalent of a type that cannot be easily taken out, we can artificially put it in an Option and use this pattern
if let Some(mut content) = self.my_option.take() {
  // mutate content while using self
  // ...
  self.my_option = Some(content);
}


Thank you so much for your answer! This looks really promising and seems to be exactly what i needed, i will try it right now! Just one question, this will not make my code unsafe or anything, right?

@MarshiDev no, this in not unsafe, all of this relies on safe operations from the standard library. Moreover, as stated here, this does not introduce any significant overhead since it relies internally on a few pointer/integer swap.
